# Magento newsletter on footer

Tags: magento

Guys where can i find template that rendering `SIGN UP FOR OUR NEWSLETTER` on footer of magento template?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can go throw this step to show from where is comes from

```
1. Open the admin control panel
2. Open the system tab and select configuration
3. Select Main Website or Name of your website (NOT DEFAULT CONFIG) from the Current 4.Configuration Scope drop down
5.Select Developer on the left sidebar
6.Open the Debug drop down
7.Set Template Path Hints To Yes
```

Click on Save Config to save down your changes

And also you can find in your xml like this

```
 <block type="newsletter/subscribe" name="left.newsletter" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"/>
```

just check which is your parent tag.

Comment: thats good hints, but Sign up for our newsletter dont points to any template.

Comment: have you checked with hint path from where it comes ? and what do you mean by points to template ?

Answer (score 0):

Alternate Solution:
go to the template file: app\design\frontend\package\theme\template\page\html\footer.phtml
 and place the following script in it, you needs.

```
{{block type="newsletter/subscribe" template="newsletter/subscribe.phtml"}}
```